# How To Apply Multiple Conditions on Case-Otherwise Statement Using Spark Dataframe API

Tags: r, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to add a new column to an existing data frame using the `withColumn` statement in `Spark Dataframe API`. The below code works but I was wondering if there's a way that I can select more than one group. Let's say Group 1, 2, 3, 4 instead of only Group 1. I think I may be able to write `when` statement four times. I have seen people do that in some posts. However, in `R`, there is a `%in%` operator that can specify if a variable contains values in a vector, but I don't know if there's such thing in Spark. I checked on the Spark API documentation but most of the functions don't contain any examples.

```
# R Sample Code:
 library(dplyr)
 df1 <- df %>% mutate( Selected_Group = (Group %in% 1:4))
```

Spark Dataframe Sample Code That Selects Group 1:

```
 val df1 = df.withColumn("Selected_Group", when($"Group" === 1, 1).otherwise(0))
```

> Data
>
> ID, Group
>    1,  0
>    2,  1
>    3,  2
>    .   .
>    .   .
>   100, 99

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

def in(s: Set[Int]) = udf((x: Int) => if (s.contains(x)) 1 else 0)
df.withColumn("Selected_Group", in((1 to 4).toSet)($"group"))
```

With raw SQL:

```
df.registerTempTable("df")
sqlContext.sql(
    "SELECT *, CAST(group IN (1, 2, 3, 4) AS INT) AS Selected_Group FROM df"
)
```

With `Column.in` method:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, when}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType

df.withColumn(
  "Selected_Group",
  $"group".in((1 to 4).map(lit): _*).cast(IntegerType))
```

or `when` function:

```
df
 .withColumn(
   "Selected_Group",
   when($"group".in((1 to 4).map(lit): _*), 1).otherwise(0))
```